# Find the Fourier series of $g (x) = f (x-a)$, where $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic and $a$ is a real number.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-series

Find the Fourier series of $g (x) = f (x-a)$, where $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic and $a$ is a real number.

This is for real analysis so I cannot use Euler's formula to compute the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Do you mean the $\cos/\sin$ Fourier series, or the exponential Fourier series. For the latter, this is really straghtforward as $a_ne^{in(x-a)}=a_ne^{-ina}e^{inx}$. For the former, there are about two extra steps, which are: trigonometric formula + linearity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $a_n$, for example,

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi g(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x-a)\cos(nx)\,dx =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(n(x+a))\,dx =\ldots $$

$$\ldots \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)(\cos(nx)\cos(na)-\sin(nx)\sin(na))\,dx=\ldots$$

$$\ldots = \cos(na)*\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx -\sin(na)*\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx =\...$$

You say the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are not given, but you will find the Fourier coefficients of $g$ in terms of those of $f$.

Comment: How do you actually solve integral (f (t-a) dt) from -pi to +pi?

Comment: @MirRafsanJami : if I understand the question correctly, you are not told what $f$ actually is, so the most you can do is express the Fourier coefficients of $g$ in terms of $a$ and the Fourier coefficients of $f$.  And of course in my answer I assume you were using the sine/cosine Fourier series, not the complex Fourier series.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Fourier coefficients for $f$, you can substitute $x \mapsto x - a$ in its expansion, and use the sum formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$ to get those for $g$...

Comment: Oh no. The fourier coefficients of f are not given. I think we have to solve it for the general case.